# Make varnish serve request from cache (cookies are cleaned)

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-54516992-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-54516992-1');
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    test
</body>
</html>
```

Backend. This is Python + Django. Please, don't be afraid. I just set a cookie here (render_to_response) and then I need a place to stop at a breakpoint (below in the code it is shown by a comment where it is).

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home/home.html"

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        response = super(TemplateView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
        response.set_cookie('sort_on', 'title')
        return response

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context # Breakpoint.
```

**varnishd** For learning purposes I just clean all cookies.

```
$ varnishd -V
varnishd (varnish-6.0.6 revision 29a1a8243dbef3d973aec28dc90403188c1dc8e7)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2019 Varnish Software AS
```

**VCL**

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    call remove_proprietary_cookies;

    if (req.http.Cookie) {      
        return (pass);
    }

}   


sub remove_proprietary_cookies{
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ".*", "");
}
```

Then I reload the page a couple of times for the cookie to be definitely there.

In Chrome:

```
document.cookie
"sort_on=title; _ga=GA1.1.988164671.1586849704; _gid=GA1.1.995393496.1586849704; _gat_gtag_UA_54516992_1=1"
```

Picture of cookies (duplicates of the text above):

[image]

Ok. We've checked that Cookie is set. Now let's check that the cookie is properly cleaned.

I stop at the braakpoint and check cookie. The value is {}.

[image]

Well. All cookies seems to be cleaned.

**The problem:**
When reloading I constantly come to the breakpoint. This means that Varnish passes the request to the backend. In other words **if (req.http.Cookie)** not working as I expect. I expect that at the previous step I have removed cookies. Then I check if cookies exist. And there shouldn't be any.

Could you help me:

1. Understand what is going on here.
2. Organize everything so that I should definitely remove cookies if I have removed them incorrectly.
3. Make Varnish serve this request from cache without passing it to the backend.

==============ADDED ON 16th of APRIL=================
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I have upgraded Varnish to 6.4:

```
michael@michael:~$ varnishd -V
varnishd (varnish-6.4.0 revision 13f137934ec1cf14af66baf7896311115ee35598)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2020 Varnish Software AS
```

**What we are going to test:**

1. Set Google Analytics cookies and a cookie at the backend.
2. Let Varnish remove all cookies and cache the response.
3. Check that request is passed to the backend only once.

Then I organized nginx behind Varnish (only to log requests). Nginx listens at 8090. This is log config:

```
   log_format  main  '[$time_local] $http_cookie';
```

Cookies:

1. In HTML I organize Google Analytics' tracking.
2. At the backend I set cookie called "sort_on" with value "title".

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**If we don't cut cookies**, the log looks this (this is just for COMPARISON):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2020:08:11:05 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" sort_on=title; _ga=GA1.1.236170900.1587013419; _gid=GA1.1.2033785209.1587013419 200 334 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36" "127.0.0.1"
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**varnish.ctl**

```
vcl 4.1;
import cookie;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8090";
}


sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    if (req.http.Cookie) {  
        return (pass);
    }   
}
```

Nginx passes requests to the backend. Backend is at port 8080.

In short what listens where:

```
Varnish - 8000
Nginx - 8090
Backend - 8080
```

Start varnishd:

```
michael@michael:~$ sudo varnishd -f /home/michael/PycharmProjects/varnish/varnish.vcl -a localhost:8000
```

Open Chrome, load the page several times:

[image]

Nginx's access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2020:08:12:49 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" - 200 334 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36" "127.0.0.1"
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2020:08:13:21 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" - 200 334 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36" "127.0.0.1"
```

We can see that cookie is absent. It is Ok. Cookies are cut off.

**Problem:** Requests are inevitably passed to the backend. I always stop at the breakpoint.

[image]

Will you be so kind as to give me a piece of advice on how to cope with the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Varnish doesn't look at the contents of the `Cookie` request header, but rather checks if the header is present.

What you need to do is to check if the `Cookie` header is empty, and if so, just remove the entire thing.

Just add this after your `regsub` statement:

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}
```

## Make the process a bit more flexible

In reality you'll probably will not remove all cookies, but just the ones that are not essential to your application.

You can use this statement to remove all cookies, except that ones you need for your application:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.Cookie) {
    set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, 
        ";(SESS[a-z0-9]+|NO_CACHE)=", "; \1=");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
      unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
    else {
      return (pass);
    }
  }
}
```

This snippet will remove all cookies, expect that ones that match the `SESS[a-z0-9]+|NO_CACHE` regex.

## Use `vmod_cookie`

There is a cleaner way to approach cookie substitution in Varnish and it involves using the `vmod_cookie` module in Varnish. You can find it here: https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/tree/master/lib/libvmod_cookie

If you upgrade to Varnish *version 6.4*, the `vmod_cookie` will be part of the core Varnish installation.

This is the equivalent using `vmod_cookie`:

```
vcl 4.1;
import cookie;

sub vcl_recv {
    cookie.parse(req.http.cookie);
    cookie.keep_re("SESS[a-z0-9]+,NO_CACHE");
    set req.http.cookie = cookie.get_string();
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll need some time to try it. Then I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: Dear Thijs, unfortunately I failed to cope with the problem. I have edited my initial question. I tried your VCL settings. The result was the same: backend is always hit. Then for simplicity just removed all cookies. Could you have a look at the addition made on 16th of April.

Comment: The `Cookie` header is one reason why Varnish doesn't want to cache. There are plenty of other reasons as well. The easiest way to find out, is by using `varnishlog`. Please make sure you have a *fresh cache* before you start, and then send me the output for the following command: `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"`, assuming the logic is on the homepage.

Based on the output, I can figure out what's going on. Please read my blog post about `varnishlog` for reference: https://feryn.eu/blog/varnishlog-measure-varnish-cache-performance/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The problem was that at the server I set a cookie. Therefore a request came from the browser, the cookie was cut off by Varnish, then the request was passed to the backend, at the backend a cookie was set. And a response with a cookie is not cached. That is why the cache was always empty.